# Issue with click on a Button or on a RelativeLayout inside a listview line with a custum adapter

Tags: android, listview, button, click, android-arrayadapter

I have to catch the click on a Button or on a RelativeLayot in my listview lines (is a Lazy List).
I'm able to do this with this code.

```
public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity _thisActivity;
    private Context _thisContext;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader;
    ArrayList<ApplicationObject> apps;
    private int pos=0;

public LazyAdapter(Activity activity,Context context, ArrayList<ApplicationObject> app) 
{
    _thisActivity = activity;
    _thisContext = context;
    inflater =   (LayoutInflater)_thisActivity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    imageLoader=new ImageLoader(_thisActivity.getApplicationContext());
    apps=app;
}

public int getCount() {
    return apps.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{


    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_listview_line4, null);

    pos=position;

    TextView title=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    title.setText(apps.get(position).getTitle());

    ImageView image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(apps.get(position).getImageSource(), image);

    TextView description=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    description.setText(shortDescription);


    RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)vi.findViewById(R.id.oggettoRL);
    rl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent i = new Intent(_thisContext,AppCompleteDescription.class);
            i.putExtra("app", apps.get(pos));
            _thisContext.startActivity(i);

        }
    });


    Button bugReport = (Button)vi.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    bugReport.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent i = new Intent(_thisContext,BugReportActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("id", apps.get(pos).getId());
            _thisContext.startActivity(i);
        }
    });


    return vi;
}

}
```

But it dosn't take the correct line number.. it is how if "position" is set with the last value inserted in the list. How can I catch the exact item clicked?

I call the adapter in this way:

```
final ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
LazyAdapter lazy = new LazyAdapter(_thisActivity,_thisContext,listaApplicationObject);
list.setAdapter(lazy);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following in your `onListemClick` --

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, final int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);  

Log.i("the Item clicked is :: ",  position);

}
```

Comment: But using this code in my Activity how can I understand if is clicked the button or the layout? So is an error set the onclicklistener directly in the custum adapter?